# Mount point doesn't exist, make directory, then "File exists" error

Tags: mount

My SD card will occasionally become unmounted.  If I try to mount it again, I get

`$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o exec /dev/mmcblk1 /var/host/media/removable/sd
mount: mount point /var/host/media/removable/sd does not exist`

Then I create this directory

`$ sudo mkdir /var/host/media/removable/sd`

and when I try to mount again, I get

`$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o exec /dev/mmcblk1 /var/host/media/removable/sd
mount: File exists`

I'm particularly puzzled by this last error message.

Comment: are you using automount? (...) The cards gets mounted automatically after you create the dir

Comment: I have the same issue, just started yesterday when I reformatted my SD card as ext4. Perhaps a clue? In my case, it's a Chromebook running Ubuntu in a chroot, and the SD cards unmounts every time the system wakes from sleep. Somewhere in the interaction between ChromeOS and the "crouton" scripts that set up the chroom, the SD card normally does automount. Probably ChromeOS does the automount. Previously, it would succeed in automounting but be marked noexec, so I'd have to remount it manually, which was a drag but I was used to it. Now I can't mount it at all. Maybe ChromeOS can't handle ext4?

Comment: Same setup for me. I found that if I exit Crouton and then manually eject and reinsert the SD card, everything is fine. It can be a pain sometimes to have to exit Crouton, but at least I get my SD card back.